# I'm trying to compare 2 variables with my enum's type

Tags: java, android-studio, enums, operators

I created an Enum wearState and then gave wearState as a type for two variables. But when I try to put them in a if condition with '||' or '&&', it doesn't work.
It says : "error : bad operand types for binary operator '||' "

```
enum wearState {
        WRIST_MOVE,
        WRIST_IMMOBILE,
        BELT_NECK_MOVE,
        BELT_NECK_IMMOBILE,
        OTHER_IMMOBILE_STATE;
    }


enum chargingState {
        YES,
        NO,
    }

wearState lastState;
wearState currentState;
chargingState lastStateCharging;
chargingState currentStateCharging;

if (((currentState = wearState.BELT_NECK_IMMOBILE) || (currentState = wearState.WRIST_IMMOBILE)) && 
    (lastStateCharging = chargingState.NO)) {

              /* .... */
 }
```

Comment: Compare with `==`, not `=` . Single `=` is for assigning a value only .

Comment: You are doing an assignment currentState = wearState.BELT_NECK_IMMOBILE
no matter which value currentState had originally, after this condition, it's value is BELT_NECK_IMMOBILE, you need to use == instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (((currentState == wearState.BELT_NECK_IMMOBILE) || (currentState == wearState.WRIST_IMMOBILE)) && 
(lastStateCharging == chargingState.NO))
```

while comparing whether two variables please use "==", 
= is an assignment operator.
it can be used only for assigning a value to variable like,

```
String name="Joe";
```

to compare to variable we should use comparison operators.
==,<=,>=,!=,<,>
are the comparison operators;

Comment: so far you add no additional information when compared to the comments. You don't even state why it should be == instead of =

Comment: thank you for info. i didn't notice the above comments

Comment: don't recommend to compare 'variables' using ==. Especially not if later on you use a String variable as example how = is assigning a value. == should only be used for primitives, singletons (why even) and enums